# Database Schema, pointer to file

Tags: sql, database, schema

This is probably a really simple question, but just making sure. I am designing a database schema and some of tables should link to files on the file system (PDF, PPT, etc).

How should this be done?

My initial idea is varchar(255) with the absolute/relative path to the file. Is there a better way to do this? I've searched online and found varbinary(max), but not sure if that's what I actually want; I don't wish to actually load any binary into the database, merely to have a pointer to a file.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach, but which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the OS and the max length of a valid path. What you are calling a "pointer" is just a text field with the file path, so no different than other character data.

I would usually store the relative path, and have the root folder specified in my application. This way you can move files to a different drive, for example, and not have to udpate the rows in your db.

The actual data type you choose depends on the dbms you are using. Some databases also provide specific data types for files that you may want to explore, e.g., the [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695918.aspx) data type introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store in the database de name of the file, and it's path, is that right? Then you should create a fild with varchar(255). I always used like that and never had problems. 
Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store the file's binary data in the database, then storing the path is the only way to go. Whether you store the absolute path or the relative path is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yep that's basically it.
Relative path from some location configured as a parameter in Db is the usual way of it.
Aside from getting round length restrictions.

If you had say C:MySystem\MyData as the base path. Then you could do Images\MyImageFile.jpg, Docs\MyDopc.pdf etc.

Note the impact on backup and restore though. You have to do the database and the file system.

One other potential consideration is filenames have to be unique. So you If Fred and Wilma both up load Picture1.jpg, the db is okay, but the file system will be stuffed.
Usual way round this is to have a user filename and an actual filename.

So Fred's Picture1.jpg is actually p000004566.jpg

Don't forget to add code to cope with the file you think should be there has been deleted by some twit.

Also some sort of admin task to tidy up orphaned files might be in order, in the infinitely unlikely event that a coding error was made. :)

Also if the path to the file is configurable by  software, make sure you check that the account that will be doing the work has read write access, might also want to use a UNC path, but don't saddle yourself with a mapped drive.